# How to get the max value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get the max value:

[image]

Here, Catee has 3 entries and out of which I need to highlight the maximum value which is 2000

Ramox has 4 entries and need to highlight the max value i.e. 144

I tried with condition formatting but I've more than 1900 rows plus 112+ records as like Catee and Ramox and applying condition formatting individually is a cumbersome process.

Record Ace has 550 as the highest number but appeared thrice. In this case, I need highlight them all

If there a better way to highlight the same:

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you fill in the gaps first. Will make live easy. Select your 1st column `A2:A22` >> Select Special >> Empty Cells >> Type `=A2` >> Ctrl +Enter. Now conditional formatting with something like `MAXIFS()` will be a walk in the park.

Comment: I tried it. =MAXIFS($C$2:$C$23,$A$2:$A$23,A2). But I want to highlight the max value with a color. Let's max value with green

Answer (score 2):

Make it easy on yourself. My advise:

- Select `C2:C22`;
- Add conditional formatting rule based on: `=C2=MAXIFS(C$2:C$22,A$2:A$22,A2)`;
- Now, select `A2:C22`;
- Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>;
- Select: 'Special' >> 'Blanks' >> 'OK';
- Type `=A2` and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the easiest way to do, nice =)

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the `Subtotals` feature of Excel?

First, I'd advise you to add the names, as so beautifully explained in JvdV's video.
As a result, you get something like this:

[image]

Start the `SubTotals` feature, using the `Max` function:

[image]

The first result looks as:

[image]

Clicking on <kbd>2</kbd> in the margin modifies this into:

[image]

Have fun :-)

Comment: I never use this function. Neat!